# How to test an Activity that uses ActivityResult APIs?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-testing, android-instrumentation, registerforactivityresult

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#test) are quite good when it comes to testing Fragments, but there's no info on how to test an Activity that uses ActivityResult.

How should we override `activityResultRegistry` in Activity tests?

Answer (score 3):

Write your contract in a separate file so you can easily test contracts and provide your own ActivityResultRegistry at runtime to fake expected results. It's bad practice to actually call a real contract to test from activity. One of the core purposes of designing contracts was to decouple activity code from onActicityResults

```
class ImageContract(registry: ActivityResultRegistry) {

    private val contractUriResult : MutableLiveData<Uri>  = MutableLiveData(null)

    private val getPermission = registry.register(REGISTRY_KEY, ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
        contractUriResult.value = uri
    }

    fun getImageFromGallery(): LiveData<Uri> {
        getPermission.launch("image/*")
        return contractUriResult
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REGISTRY_KEY = "Image Picker"
    }
}
```

In your activity

```
 ImageContractHandler(activityResultRegistry).getImageFromGallery().observe(this, {
      it?.let { u ->
           backgroundImageView.setImageURI(u)
      }
 })
```

In your Tests

```
@Test
fun activityResultTest() {

    // Create an expected result URI
    val testUrl = "file//dummy_file.test"
    val expectedResult = Uri.parse(testUrl)

    // Create the test ActivityResultRegistry
    val testRegistry = object : ActivityResultRegistry() {
        override fun <I, O> onLaunch(
            requestCode: Int,
            contract: ActivityResultContract<I, O>,
            input: I,
            options: ActivityOptionsCompat?
        ) {
            dispatchResult(requestCode, expectedResult)
        }
    }

    val uri = ImageContractHandler(testRegistry).getImageFromGallery().getOrAwaitValue()
    assert(uri == expectedResult)
}
```

For listening LiveData on the same thread in Tests a famous livedata test extension

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
    this.observeForever(observer)

    afterObserve.invoke()

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        this.removeObserver(observer)
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't reading the docs as precisely as I should have.

> Note: Any mechanism that allows you to inject a separate `ActivityResultRegistry` in tests is enough to enable testing your activity result calls.

Emphasis on the word *inject*.

I'm using Koin in my project so I decided to use the Scopes api to create an Activity Scoped instance of `ActivityResultRegistry`, which I injected into my `registerForActivityResult`-call.

```kotlin
val activityScopeModule = module {
    scope<MyActivity> {
        scoped { get<ComponentActivity>().activityResultRegistry }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
  private val requestPermLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), 
    get<ActivityResultRegistry>()  // Koin injection
  ) { granted ->
   // handle 
  }
}
```

By using DI, injecting my custom test instance of `ActivityResultRegistry` in tests became very easy.

Useful blog post on the topic (uses Hilt to achieve the same task): https://blog.stylingandroid.com/activity-result-contract-outside-the-activity/

Blog post about Koin Scopes API: https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-android-scopes-with-koin-cfe6b60ca579